# question related to array

Tags: php

I have two array. and I want to concatenate to following format. format is shown as follows.

```
    Getting form values using post method
    /************ Getting Form names like Weight,arms Age etc **********************/
      foreach ($_POST["form_field_names"] as $key => $values) {
    $form_field_name = $values;
}

/************ Getting Form Values like 45,90,2 **********************/
foreach ($_POST["form_field_values"] as $key => $values) {
    $form_field_values[] = $values;
}

Array
(
   [0] => Age
   [1] => Weight
   [2] => Arms
)
Array
(
  [0] => 45
  [1] => 90
  [2] => 2
)
```

Want to concatenate to following format

```
$output = $Age.","."45".",".$Weight.","."90".",".$Arms.","."2".",";
```

Is it possible? thanks

Answer (score 5):

I would propose that you first merge the two arrays [into one](http://php.net/array_combine) associative array:

```
$assoc = array_combine($keys_array1, $num_array2);
```

Then it's just a matter of looping over that to generate the output string:

```
$str = "";
foreach ($assoc as $key=>$num) {
    $str .= "$key,$num,";
}
```

Should the trailing `,` be an issue (you didn't say), then I would resort to a `$str = rtrim($str, ",")` workaround afterwards.

Comment: Wasting memory by creating an intermediate array. Can be done by just one for loop see @Rob Williams's answer.

Comment: @codaddict: True, I would do that as temp in the loop. But then it's just another 1K, easily outdone by heap fragmentation or temp strings in callbacks. @Rob's idea with the `$$keyname` is eventually more relevant.

Comment: @mario `array_combine($form_field_name, $form_field_values);` is this statement is corrent? its not working.

Comment: @user559744 That looks like it's using the right array variable names. What's not working? Use print_r() again to check the content.

Comment: @mario `Warning: array_combine() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in C:\wamp\www\form\index2.php on line 18` I'm getting this warning.

Comment: @user559744: Ah okay. It seems your first `foreach` loop is missing the `[]` in the following line: `$form_field_name[] = $values;` It must be identical to the second loop to collect an array.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like an odd request, but ok... ;)

```
$output = "";

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++) {
  $output .= $array1[$i] . "," . $array2[$i] . ",";
}
```

Now, that will concatenate the strings in array1. If you're looking to concatenate the variables named after the strings in array1, a very similar loop should work:

```
$output = "";

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++) {
  $output .= $$array1[$i] . "," . $array2[$i] . ",";
}
```

I *think* that should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can 'merge' your parallel arrays

I'll call your first array `$arr1` and the second `$arr2`

```
$newArr = array();
foreach($arr1 as $k=>$v)
   $newArr[$v] = $arr2[$k];
```

Or check out `array_combine` as the other poster mentioned.  PHP has some good array functions like that and its always good to use them.

Once you have the array in this format

```
['Age'] => 45
['Weight'] => 90
['Arms'] => 2
```

You can print them the way you want as follows

```
foreach($newArr as $k=>$v)
    echo "$k: $v  "
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '';
foreach($array1 as $key => $value)
{
   $str .= $value.",". $array2[$key].",";
}
```